# How to get C# object for following JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have this kind of JSON, how can i covert to C# object with `newtonsoft`.

```
[["Newyork", "Goods & Services", "Description", "02/23/2016", "03/15/2016", "some info"]]
```

Comment: That's not a json, that's just an array. Also it is spelled New York

Comment: @EricHerlitz: Well it *is* valid JSON, it's an array with a single element which is also an array.

Comment: that's invalid `JSON`. The elements of inner array aren't key-val s

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh: In what way?

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>>(data);`

Comment: i just copied the line from the document

Comment: that's a valid one, try validating it here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I got this all wrong. Array of Array of strings. lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
string jsonString = @"[[""Newyork"", ""Goods & Services"", ""Description"", ""02/23/2016"", ""03/15/2016"", ""some info""]]";

List<string[]> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string[]>>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) to do this conversion. Like the following:

```
string inputString= @"[[""Newyork"", ""Goods & Services"", ""Description"", ""02/23/2016"", ""03/15/2016"", ""some info""]]";    
List<string[]> jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string[]>>(inputString);
```